# Casting de google chrome en app android

Tags: android, android-studio, chrome

He encontrado código para añadir la funcionalidad de Casting de google Chromecast a mi app, pero me encuentro con ciertos `imports` que no funcionan, entre estos:

```
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastMediaControlIntent;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
```

¿Hay alguna librería que debería descargar?

En cuyo caso ¿Dónde podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que implementar en build.gradle(Module:app) las siguientes librerías..

```
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.8.0'
```

Te dejo enlace a la página de google de como integrar Cast en tu aplicación. Suerte!!
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate